# fastlane: command not found when running from launchtl job

Tags: ios, terminal, fastlane, launch-agent, launchctl

Hi I made an integration to create the builds of one IOS project using fastlane.  Everything works as expected except the moment I try to launch a script to run the fastlane command on my Mac Computer using launchctl. When I run the job I get the following error:

```
/Users/hugoaguero/Documents/acct/branding/usfed/ios/scripts/test.sh: line 2: fastlane: command not found
```

This happens with the following two lines on my test script (deploy is a lane I created on the fastfile file):

```
cd ~/Documents/acct/branding/usfed/ios/
fastlane deploy
```

My pList file resides on the LaunchAgent folder.  This is the content of the pList file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.zerowidth.launched.grobankingbuild</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>sh</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>/Users/hugoaguero/Documents/acct/branding/usfed/ios/scripts/test.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.zerowidth.launched.grobankingbuild.err</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.zerowidth.launched.grobankingbuild.out</string>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>300</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

If I run the command normally from terminal it executes with no issues.  The only problem is when it runs from the job.

I'm very new to terminal/Unix, I think that it should be an easy fix but need to solve this as soon as possible. Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the full path of the fastlane executable from the command line:

```
which fastlane
```

And replace `fastlane` in your script with the full (absolute) path shown by the command here above.